# Find $A$ given $B$, $C$, $ABA^{-1} = C$ and that all are rotations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations

Given rotation matrices $A$, $B$, $C$ and knowing

$
ABA^{-1} = C
$

is it possible to recover $A$ uniquely? I know that this is not possible for general matrices, but for rotations it feels like it should be.

Comment: If $A$ is given, then the answer is obvious yes. Do you mean if $B,C$ are given and you know that $A,B,C$ are rotation matrices?

Comment: Also, in plane, if $A,B$ are rotations about $0$ then I think that $ABA^{-1}=B$ no matter what $A$ is. So when $B$ is given and $C=B$, you cannot recover $A$.

Comment: For the same reason, if $B=C$ is a 3D rotation, then every rotation $A$ with the same rotation axis as $B$ will satisfy $ABA^{-1}=C$.